# Encryption format for Woocommerce data stored in database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I am new to Wordpress and Woocommerce. Looking at the database I came to see few text columns where the stored value looks something like this:

> a:23:s:16:"woofc_last_added";s:32:"d770c2ff0c2b832aad82b0cbc3f144a6";s:21:"removed_cart_contents";s:6:"a:0:{}";s:10:"wc_notices";N;s:8:"customer";s:775:"a:25:}

I have stripped most of the fields, but it looks somewhat like this.

What format is this? 
How can I parse values in this format? 
How can I retrieve all the values from this text data in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The data is in a serialized protected format**

> You could try to use `json_decode()`, `unserialize()` or `maybe_unserialize()` functions, 
> **But you will not get any data** as it's a **`WC_Session_Handler`** stored **PROTECTED** object.

You will need to use instead [**`WC_Session_Handler`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session_Handler.html) or [**`WC_Session`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Session.html#methods) available methods.

1) To get the current customer **`WC_Session_Handler`** object you can use:

```
// Get the current WC_Session_Handler obect
$session_obj = WC()->session;

print_r($session_obj); // Raw output
```

2) To get the  **`WC_Session_Handler`** object from a defined customer ID

```
// The defined customer ID
$customer_id = 5;     
// Get an Instance of the WC_Session_Handler object
$new_session_obj = new WC_Session_Handler();    
// The defined customer ID
$session_obj = $new_session_obj->get_session( $customer_id );
```

3) Accessing the protected data:

```
## --- Get the data in an array (values are still serialized) --- ##

$session_data_array = WC()->session->get_session_data();
print_r($session_data_array); // Raw output


## -------------- Get the cleaned unserialized data ------------- ##

$session_cart = WC()->session->get('cart');
$session_cart_totals = WC()->session->get('cart_totals');
$session_applied_coupons = WC()->session->get('applied_coupons');
$session_coupon_discount_totals = WC()->session->get('coupon_discount_totals');
$session_coupon_discount_tax_totals = WC()->session->get('coupon_discount_tax_totals');
$session_removed_cart_contents = WC()->session->get('removed_cart_contents');
$session_shipping_for_package_0 = WC()->session->get('shipping_for_package_0');
$session_previous_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('previous_shipping_methods');
$session_chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods');
$session_shipping_method_counts = WC()->session->get('shipping_method_counts');
$session_customer = WC()->session->get('customer');

// Raw "Cart" output example
print_r(WC()->session->get('cart'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just wanted to know how the data is parsed. The data looks compressed and so I thought I could use it in a php application where I have lots of fields to store in the database. The data is more like comments, notes etc by our users.

Comment: The data is not compressed. In Wordpress, all arrays or objects stored in database are always serialized… Here, as it's a custom WooCommerce table with sensible data, this data is serialized but protected, so you will not be able to unserialize it from the database. Now you can build your own functions code to parse this data and save it in a custom table using WC_Session_Handler class and methods…

Comment: Do you have any idea on how often woocommerce updates this field? When does this field gets updated? Is it when the session ends or on specific method executions?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a JSON format it is simple a way wordpress save arrays in serialized format in its tables. 
Just use php unserialized function, it will unserialize this and you will be able to parse it in normal php array format.  You can view this function documentation here http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 0):

It stores in serialized format. You can get normal array by using unserialized function.

`unserialize()`